# Png To Base64 string background turns black

Tags: c#, highcharts, ms-word, webapi

When I convert my png image to base64 string to add html it's background turns black at output html.

```
private string ImageToBase64(string Path)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/ReportResource/HighchartImage/" + Path)))
        {

            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

            }
        }
    }
```

It will great help if you have any solution.

Comment: .png supports transparency. And it has become somewhat of a default to use it, rather then monocrome filling. Any chance you just used a different background color?

Comment: i did'nt used any background color. in order to solve this issue i tried by adding css background color white on image tag but is not worked.

Comment: you read the file stream into an image class to write it into a memory stream to convert that into base64. You can convert the file stream into base64 directly

Comment: please suggest example if have any...

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String( File.ReadAllBytes( Path ) );

Comment: @SirRufo same problem exists!

Comment: Your question is not related to Highcharts and Highcharts .NET wrapper. https://dotnet.highcharts.com/ If you still have a problem I suggest to do base64 via using some online tool and this method should return the string type. You should be able to see if you have something wrong in your HTML or in conversion.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel As I am downloading that image from highchart export client server as png format then i am converting it as base64 to bind html to convert  that html as word doc file so everything is related to each other.. and i can't understand the actual issue.. but i think  base64 conversion possibly the issue creator, so i point out all related tool.

Comment: @SaifulIslam Are you able to share your project or just a sample of it? Our .NET supporter will try to reproduce your problem. You can reach me: sebastian.wedzel@blacklabel.pl